# How Can I Get a List of All Files I've Changed Through Git

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

I'm trying to generate a list of all files that I've changed since commit X.  I've tried using `git log`:

```
git log --author="Me" --stat commitX..
```

That works great, except it shows me the files changed *per commit*, whereas I just want a single (unique) file list of all the files changed across *all commits*.

I've also tried using `git diff`:

```
git diff --name-only --author="Me" commitX..
```

But the `diff` command doesn't respect the `--author` argument, so while I get a combined, unique file list, that list also includes all of my co-workers' changes.

Is there any way to use either command (or a third command for that matter) to do:

```
git whatever --author="Me" commitX..

myChangedFile1.foo
myChangedFile2.bar
etc.
```

P.S. Bonus points if I can swap `--stat` for `--p` and still use the same command (ie. if there is a way I can also see the combined diff across the list of returned files, instead of just the list).

Comment: agree with @infused. the only addition (based on one of the answers in there is the commit range): `git log --stat --no-merge --author="case-sensitive" --name-only --pretty=format:"" hash1..HEAD | sort -u`

Comment: Kinda sad that git doesn't actually have any way of doing this built-in, but that other post did answer my question. Thanks!